# Appsync Resolver ResponseMappingTemplate- Direct mapping vs Template mapping

Tags: aws-appsync

I have the following ResponseMappingTemplate in AWS::AppSync::Resolver which does NOT work (following the doc from aws https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-http-resolvers.html )

```
ResponseMappingTemplate: |
        {
          #if($ctx.result.statusCode == 200)
            $ctx.result.body
          #else
            $utils.appendError($ctx.result.body, "$ctx.result.statusCode")
          #end
        }
```

The above giving me error:

> "message": "Unable to convert {\n
>   [{\"employeeId\":10901},{\"employeeId\":11352}]\n  } to class
>   java.lang.Object."

However it works ok for direct mapping like so:

```
ResponseMappingTemplate: $ctx.result.body
```

i really don't understand, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON blurb you posted doesn't seem to be valid.

```
{\n
[{\"employeeId\":10901},{\"employeeId\":11352}]\n }
```

there seem to be an extra `{}` around your list. A JSON object must have keys defined.

Comment: assuming you were correct that the json was not valid, then why "ResponseMappingTemplate: $ctx.result.body"  worked ? 

anyway. the extra {} being added by the ResponseMappingTemplate output itself. i checked it appsync output log in cloudwatch

Comment: $ctx.result.body probably worked because it only contained the Json encoded string you provided. With the HTTP data source the result body is always a string and not an object because AppSync can’t infer whether the body is of type json, text, xml or another format.